# ASP.NET MVC routing with non standard controller name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need url for editing friends in my ASP.NET MVC site like this:

```
site.com/friend{x}/edit
```

where `{x}` - id of friend.

So, how should I use my ActionLinks, Controller name and Routings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your control is called `FriendController`, try adding a custom route such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Friends", // Route name
  "friend{id}/{action}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Friend", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then you would construct your ActionLinks, etc. exactly as normal.